# Adding views programmatically, then referencing those views.

Tags: javascript, android, android-relativelayout

I'm a novice in the java world, so thanks in advance for the help.

What I am trying to do is this: 
I have two EditText fields and a Button. When I hit the button, I want to take the contents of the two fields, combine them and display them below button. The fields are cleared. Then if they are filled again and the button is pushed, combine the fields and display them below previously generated textview.

Example:

### Before Button Click:

eT1___ eT2____ |Button|

### After Button click

eT1___ eT2____ |Button|
               eT1-eT2

### After 2nd Button click

eT1___ eT2____ |Button|
               eT1-eT2
               eT1-eT2

And so on however many times the button is clicked. What I need help with is the new views that are being added. Currently I am using a Relative Layout. What I am trying to figure out is how to reference the new textView's that I am creating within the code so that when new views are added, they can reference the previously added view.

This is what I've been attempting at the moment:

```js
private TextView createNewTextView(String desc, Double cost){
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);;
        TextView newTextView = new TextView(this);
        if (i==1) {
            lparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, mButton.getId());
        }
        else {
            lparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, mLayout.getId());
        }
        lparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        newTextView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        newTextView.setText(desc + " - $" + cost);
        newTextView.setTag(i);
        i++;
        return newTextView;
    }
```

I was trying to use "i" as an incrementing variable that I could use to reference the previous view by except on the first pass when it the new view references based on the button.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance and for everything I've lurked already!

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?  You are more likely to get help if you clearly state exactly what is wrong.

Comment: I am trying to get the new textView that is created on the first button click to appear underneath the button. Then all subsequent textViews that are created on button clicks will appear below the last created textView. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a member variable of `ArrayList` of `TextView` :

```
ArrayList<TextView> textviews = new ArrayList<>();
```

and then in your `createNewTextView()` method, store the reference of `TextView` you are adding:

```
textviews.add(newTextView);
```

So the `TextView` you've added at the first will be at index 0 and so on. Then you can easily reference your `TextViews`.

Suppose you want to get the second `TextView`,

```
TextView secondTv = textviews.get(1);
```

Comment: This seems to be working better for me but I'm still missing something. My first created textView is placed perfectly but my then my next one is shown in the top left corner and all new created views then are placed on top of each other. Does this look right `code`lparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, textviews.get(i-1).getId() )"`code`

Comment: So close now... I added `textviews.get(i).setId(i);` to the `createNewTextView()` method. Now the new textViews build are placed below the previous textView with the exception of the second one. When I first press the button, the new view is placed below the button like I want. On the next click, the view is added below the top of the parent. On the next click, the view is added below the previous view. Just need to get that second click acting correctly and I'll be all set.

Comment: Can you post your whole code and the changes you've made.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your textviews to a global list and find them based on the tag from there.